# Django not working with Angularjs

Tags: html, django, angularjs

When I open the file `angular.html` the angularjs with Chrome, the html work normally, showing the array of information in the table. However, when I use Django, the same angular.html file, angularjs does not show the array of information in the table. I do not know what can I do?

File **angular.html**

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function tabela($scope){
            $scope.linhas2=[["Nexus S1","Oi1"],["Nexus S2","Oi2"],["Nexus S3","Oi3"]]               
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="tabela">
        <table>
            <tr ng-model="item2" ng-repeat="item2 in linhas2">
                <td ng-repeat="item3 in item2">{{ item3 }}</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def ang(request):
    return render_to_response("angular.html")
```

File **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^angular/','bvmfconsulta.views.ang'),
)
```

The Django finds `angular.html` but shows a blank page.

Comment: To prevent mix up of Angularjs with Django: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27282607/2412381

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that both Django and AngularJS share the same syntax for variable substitution in templates.

The easiest option would be to tell Django not to use it's syntax in places you need to use angularjs variable substitution - in other words, use [`verbatim` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim):

```
{% verbatim %}
    <div ng-controller="tabela">
        <table>
            <tr ng-model="item2" ng-repeat="item2 in linhas2">
                <td ng-repeat="item3 in item2">{{ item3 }}</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

See other options at:

- [Integrate AngularJS with Django](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html#template-tags)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you can use the **{% verbatim %}** tag. There is another way: you can change the AngularJS tags:

```
var app = angular.module('dashboardApp').config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
```

Your code will transform to:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function tabela($scope){
            $scope.linhas2=[["Nexus S1","Oi1"],["Nexus S2","Oi2"],["Nexus S3","Oi3"]]               
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="tabela">
        <table>
            <tr ng-model="item2" ng-repeat="item2 in linhas2">
                <td ng-repeat="item3 in item2">{$ item3 $}</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This way you can visually distinguish between Angular and Django Template tags. Cheers!